# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(...)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to use recyclerView in my acitivity's fragment, but I have this error:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference.

I can't understand why it's null.

This is my fragment (ProceduresFragment)

```
package com.example.ddd;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.ddd.Models.PerformedMessage;
import com.example.ddd.Models.Procedure;
import com.example.ddd.Models.VisitPlace;
import com.example.ddd.dummy.DummyContent;
import com.example.ddd.dummy.DummyContent.DummyItem;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

/**
 * A fragment representing a list of Items.
 * <p/>
 * Activities containing this fragment MUST implement the {@link OnListFragmentInteractionListener}
 * interface.
 */
public class ProceduresFragment extends Fragment {


    // TODO: Customize parameter argument names
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    // TODO: Customize parameters
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
     * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public ProceduresFragment() {
    }

    // TODO: Customize parameter initialization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static ProceduresFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        ProceduresFragment fragment = new ProceduresFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }

    }

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_procedures_list, container, false);


        procedures = new ArrayList<>();
        //get procedures
        if(!getProcedures())
            Helper.ShowAlert("Error",getContext());


        recyclerView = view.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.procedures_list);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration =
                new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), layoutManager.getOrientation());

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

        //adapter
        MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter(procedures, mListener);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        /*
        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter(procedures, mListener));
        }
        */

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnListFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnListFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnListFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onListFragmentInteraction(Procedure item);
    }
```

this is fragment_procedures.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/procedures_list_recycler"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="512dp">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is fragment_procedures_list.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/procedures_list"
    android:name="com.example.ddd.ProceduresFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".ProceduresFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item" />
```

this is recycler_view_item.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/procedure_select"
      android:layout_width="30dp"
      android:layout_height="35dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/procedure_name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
      android:textColor="@android:color/black"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/procedure_select"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.ddd;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.ddd.Models.Procedure;
import com.example.ddd.ProceduresFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener;
import com.example.ddd.dummy.DummyContent.DummyItem;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that can display a {@link DummyItem} and makes a call to the
 * specified {@link OnListFragmentInteractionListener}.
 * TODO: Replace the implementation with code for your data type.
 */
public class MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Procedure> mValues;
    private final OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Procedure> items, OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
        mValues = items;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_procedures, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.procedureName.setText(mValues.get(position).getName());

        if(holder.mItem.isChecked()){
            holder.selectionState.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            holder.selectionState.setChecked(false);
        }

        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (null != mListener) {
                    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                    mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public final View mView;
        public TextView procedureName;
        public CheckBox selectionState;

        public Procedure mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;

            procedureName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.procedure_name);
            selectionState = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.procedure_select);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);

            selectionState.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        Toast.makeText(procedureName.getContext(),"Selected Procedure is" +
                                " " + procedureName.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + procedureName.getText() + "'";
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

this is logcat:

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2018-10-09 18:11:51.106 3086-3086/com.example.ddd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ddd, PID: 3086
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.ddd.MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter.java:84)
        at com.example.ddd.MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter.java:37)
        at com.example.ddd.MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyProceduresRecyclerViewAdapter.java:23)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17702)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17702)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1858)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17702)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17702)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:443)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17702)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17702)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1762)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1606)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1515)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17702)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:325)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:774)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17702)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5631)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2519)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2234)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6774)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:926)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:912)
2018-10-09 18:11:51.106 3086-3086/com.example.ddd E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inflating wrong layout

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_procedures, parent, false);
```

Replace `R.layout.fragment_procedures` with `R.layout.recycler_view_item`